# Data is not stored in Firebasae Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When the "Add Item to the menu" button is clicked it will show "item added" which means it should be added to my firebase database, but when I check it nothing is showing meaning it was not stored. :(

Here are my codes

```
public class addItem extends AppCompatActivity{
private Button btnAdd;
private EditText name,desc,price;
private StorageReference storageReference = null;
private DatabaseReference mRef;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    desc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
    price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Item");
}
public  void addItemToMenu(View v)
{
    final String name_text = name.getText().toString().trim();
    final String desc_text = desc.getText().toString().trim();
    final String price_text = price.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name_text) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_text) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(price_text))
    {
        Toast.makeText(addItem.this, "Item Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final DatabaseReference newPost = mRef.push();
        newPost.child("name").setValue(name_text);
        newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_text);
        newPost.child("price").setValue(price_text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your database rules to:

```
{
 "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: While this solves the problem, I must point out that it leaves the database public which means that anyone (literally) can access the data stored.

Answer (score 1):

check the rules for firebase in your firebase console and change rules according to your scenario..